# customization is possible with serialization then why Externalizable at all?

Tags: java, serialization, serializable, externalizable

I have read these articles on `SO`:

[Externalizable or Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221303/externalizable-or-serializable),

[What is the difference between Serializable and Externalizable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817853/what-is-the-difference-between-serializable-and-externalizable-in-java?rq=1).

but my question is what extra customization could be derived by implementing `Externalizable` as compared to `serializable`.

It is possible to customize `Serialization` of a `class` that implements `Serializable` by giving our own implementation of `writeObject` and `readObject`. Then what is the purpose of using  `Externalizable` and customizing the `ReadExternal` and `writeExternal` implementations. what is the real benefit of using `Externalizable`. I have read various links that says `Externalizable` supports custom `serialization` (including the one above). but I do not see an example where `Externalizable` is a clear winner or something that cannot be done using `Serializable`. would be nice to see an example on this.

Just to give more clarity, the following snippet,  is extracted from [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/customize-default-serialization-protocol/):

When a `class` implements `Serializable interface` it gives information to the `JVM` that the `instances` of these `classes` can be serialized. Along with that, there is a special note to the `JVM`

"look for following two methods in the class that implements Serializable. If found invoke that and continue with serialization process else directly follow the standard serialization protocol"

So this gives us a chance to write these two methods:

`private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;`, 
`private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;`

inside the `Class` that implements `Serializable` and you get a hook to the `serialization` process. You can write your custom code inside these two methods and customize the standard behavior of `serialization`.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Serializable and Externalizable is that Serializable automatically takes care of base classes for you. Externalizable leaves the entire job up to you.